# When I click Get location button, app freezes on Permission screen on iOS simulator

Tags: android-studio, flutter, geolocation, ios-simulator

I am running into an issue when trying to get a current location in my flutter app. I am using the Geolocator package. The current version is [Geolocator 5.0.1](https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-geolocator) I am able to get a location on an actual android device but in an iOS simulator (using Android Studio), the code gets stuck on a Permission Screen (freezes) an no matter what I press it does not proceed. Please help

[image]

Comment: try it a real device instead

Comment: Yeah that's fine, but that does not solve the problem that it is supposed to work on the simulator